# vb .net, simple report

Tags: vb.net

I need a very simple reporting in my VB .NET app, like old days HTML pages: few colored headers, images, tables and texts. The problem is I really don't know where to start, more precisely which (reporting) tool? Should I dig on native Microsoft reporting tool? Another option is to use a webbrowser component and to try to display some in-memory generated page.

Asking because I use MySql and I already wrote my procedures to populate dgv, combos programatically so I haven't any datasources, dataset, dataadapters, etc. Just executing queries and fill datatables.

Thanks for your comments,

Comment: You should first try to define what you want. Then start searching for it. What have you looked for so far?

Comment: Well, I tried native Report and FastReport but both are far much complex than I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with small and simple reports I can recommand [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/). I used it to generate a basic .pdf-Report with some Labels, text and graphics It's easy and capable for most things. It's free for non-commercial usage.

Additionally spotted this [Alternative from iText](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/?snippetChooser=various) which seems to convert Xml->Pdf. Might be worth a try, too?

Comment: Thank you very much sir, I'll try iTextSharp next days

Answer (score 0):

If you're using one of the paid Visual Studio packages, there's reporting built in. I think it used to be Crystal Reports. I'm not sure if this is available in the free tools or not.

Depending on your needs, you could also go with formatted datagrids or output HTML in a datalist, the advantage there being you could do pretty much anything you wanted to. I'd probably go this route because it sounds like your reporting is really simple, and using a package may be overpowered for what you need to do.